# Can someone explain what this does "defaultdict(lambda:0)"

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, defaultdict

Hey so Im trying to use this code that someone wrote to calculate if someone has a poker one pair in a given hand
I understand how the code works but my only question is how exactly does this one work?

```
value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
```

I tried replacing this line of code with a standard dictionary using {} and it wouldn't work. It said keyerror: 3. I attached the entire code block for reference. lmk

```
values = [i[0] for i in hand]
value_counts = defaultdict(lambda:0)
for v in values:
    value_counts[v]+=1

if 2 in value_counts.values():
    return True
else:
    return False
```